# Using autolayout to fix custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, constraints

I need help to understand how to use autolayout. I watched a couple of videos on youtube and read apples documentation about it but its really hard to grasp how it works.

I have a simple UITableView with a couple of IBOutlets that needs to change positions as there are different sizes of iPhone/iPad. You can see my problem in the image below.

[image]

The image to the left is my storyboard, those to pictures to the left shows how it would look like in 4 inch and 4.7 inch.

As you can see the score labels are not visible. How can i fix this.. A step by step guide would be nice since I'm REALLY confused with constraints.. Thanx!!

Comment: Score label set TOP,BOTTOM,TRAILING of Cell and WIDTH,HEIGHT of lebel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you do this for the first score label you will define the TOP, TRAILING and BOTTOM constraints of the label so it could know where to place the label. But you still need to define the size of the label with the constraints WIDTH and HEIGHT. You could also define de size of the label using its intrinsic size, but you can start by defining the fixed WIDTH and Height constraints.
￼  [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsKUp.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4YC3.png
[image]

Then, you need to define the constraints for de second score label. For that you need to define the Bottom and trailing constraints and Width and Height constraints. You don’t need to define the top constraint because it was already defined in the first score label. Check the next figure! =D
￼[image]

Comment: You used the same pictures? @marciojoaquim

Comment: It worked thank you!
I got a couple of questions. I dont get it why dont i need to define a top constraint for the second label?
The first label's top constraint is from that label to the top container view right?. And the second label's top constraint should be from the label to the other label if im not wrong? Then should not the constraints be different?

Also when dealing with constraints. Do i need to put any constraints on the labels to the left like the hometeam, awayteam etc? Seems to be looking good but am i supposed to do it? @marciojoaquim

Comment: I have created a new project to demonstrate you this case!

Comment: You don't need to create a top constraint because for the first label you have defined a bottom constraint, that basically is a constraint defined between the first and the second labels. So this already defines a constraint for both labels.

Comment: Ahhh wonderful! Lol stupid of me that i did not think of that. Where did you learn constraints? Cause i have one other example i am trying to fix and im trying to use the same "thinking" or method but it's not working. @marciojoaquim

Comment: I am using Auto Layout since the launch of iOS 7. It is tricky. I study lots of auto layout tutorials throughout the internet, and Apple docs about that. I also view the videos from WWDC that you can get in apple developers portal

Comment: Is there anyway i can communicate with you regarding my other problems to learn how to think? It should not be so hard or complex.? @mariojoaquim